# super.paint() not visible over image

Tags: java, image, swing, overriding, graphics2d

I'm building a JFrame with an image as a background. I'm overriding the paint() method to draw that image in the JFrame, but when I start the application in Eclipse, none of the JComponents I added are visible. Here's my SSCCE:

```
public class foo extends JFrame{

   Image i = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://pittsburgh.about.com/library/graphics/regatta_balloons-640.jpg"));

   foo(){
       setSize(100, 100);
       add(new JButton("Foo"));
       setVisible(true);
   }

   @Override public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawImage(i, 0, 0, null);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't override the paint() method of JFrame!!! That is NOT how custom painting is done.

If you are trying to add a background image to your frame then check out [Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) for a couple of approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Statements are executed in the order specified by you. If you place `g.drawImage` *after* `super.paint(g);` it will draw the image *after* the other stuff is draw, i.e. *over* the other stuff. It's like all kind of paintings. What you draw later will be over the previously draw.

Comment: The problem with placing super.paint(g) after is that I see a gray background instead of the image I want drawn.

Comment: Did you check whether your image really has been loaded correctly? Putting an http url into a `File` looks very strange to be. Though it might work by accident.

Comment: I clicked copy image location to get the image url, but that wa only for the purposes of the SSCCE. In my real program, it's in a local folder, and I wasn't sure how to post an SSCCE with an image without an http url.

Comment: Then the only thing is that you should have replaced `File` with `URL`.

Comment: OK...can't believe I didn't think of that. Corrected.

Comment: By the way when I test your code (with `URL`) it does what I expected. It paints the image over the button so the button can't be seen unless I force it by hoovering/clicking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good [tutorial](http://java-demos.blogspot.se/2012/09/setting-background-image-in-jframe.html) on how to set the background of a JFrame.

```
JLabel background=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Computer\\Downloads\\colorful design.png"));
add(background);
background.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

OR

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Computer\\Downloads\\colorful design.png")));
```